# How to efficiently compare a list of string within a dictionaries against another list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary, for-loop

I would like to compare a list of string within a dictionaries against another list of dictionaries in Python. If the `href` in the `secondary_list` is unavailable in the `main_list`, the `href` will be appended into the `main_list`.

Based on this requirement,the code below was realized.

```
main_list = [
    {'href': 'red'},
    {'href': 'yellow'},
    {'href': 'yellow'},
]

secondary_list = [
    {'href': 'yellow'},
    {'href': 'redf'},
    {'href': 'blue'},
]
for g in secondary_list:

    if not any(d.get('href', None) == g["href"] for d in main_list):
        main_list.append({'href': g["href"]})
```

But, say if we have a very large list in both dictionary, the implementation using two for loops may be inefficient.

May I know whether the code above can be make more efficient and compact? Even better, if there exist package that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following, `O(n)` complexity:

```
main_set = {frozenset(g.items()) for g in main_list}
secondary_set = {frozenset(g.items()) for g in secondary_list}

main_list.extend(dict(g) for g in secondary_set - main_set)
print(main_list)
```

**Output**

```
[{'href': 'red'}, {'href': 'yellow'}, {'href': 'yellow'}, {'href': 'blue'}, {'href': 'redf'}]
```

The idea is to create sets of frozen dictionaries `frozenset(g.items())` find the difference and convert back to dictionaries. You can think of [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) as a *hashable set*.

For your case in particular, single key dictionaries where the key is the same for all, you could do:

```
main_set = {v for d in main_list for v in d.values()}
secondary_set = {v for d in secondary_list for v in d.values()}

main_list.extend({"href": v} for v in (secondary_set - main_set))
print(main_list)
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion by reducing it into O(n) complexity. I still dont have the large dic at the time being hence unable to compare the difference in execution time. But, I will update later the speed gain by applying your proposed solution.